# How to take a heap dump with Eclipse OpenJ9?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump, openj9

With Oracle's Hotspot JVM, it looks like `jmap -dump:file=/tmp/dump.txt <pid>` can be used to take a heap dump.

However, Eclipse OpenJ9 doesn't include the `jmap` tool - and if you try to use the regular `jmap` with OpenJ9's jvm, it gives the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.tools.attach.attacher.OpenJ9VirtualMachine incompatible with sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine
    at java.lang.ClassCastException.<init>(java.base@10.0.2-adoptopenjdk/ClassCastException.java:71)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.executeCommandForPid(jdk.jcmd@10.0.2-adoptopenjdk/JMap.java:128)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.dump(jdk.jcmd@10.0.2-adoptopenjdk/JMap.java:192)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(jdk.jcmd@10.0.2-adoptopenjdk/JMap.java:110)
```

So, how can one take a heap dump with OpenJ9?

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/5317) jmap should be part of the current/upcoming release.

Comment: Thanks, what should I do this in the meantime? @Thomas

Comment: Hmm, I'm no OpenJ9 expert yet (we're currently discussing to switch) but it seems as if you could use Eclipse MAT to connect to the JVM and acquire a dump or use [-Xdump](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/xdump/) options to enable various dump agents (e.g. "heap") and events (e.g. "user").

Comment: @Thomas Yeah I tried reading the `-xdump` documentation and I think I'm an experienced dev but I can't figure out which options I'd need or how to use them. All I want is to take a dump before and after taking a particular action.

Comment: It looks like it only produces dumps for particular events. I want to trigger the dump myself.

Comment: Well, I didn't use those options either but according to the documentation the event type "user" should allow you to send an event to the process. Another option might be using [JMX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/mxbeans.html), e.g. via jconsole.

Answer (score 2):

An OpenJ9 heap dump can be created with the command `jcmd <PID> Dump.heap <path>.phd`.

For example:

```sh
jcmd 1 Dump.heap /tmp/heap-dump.phd
```

Notice:

- It must be run as the same user that the JVM is running as.
- The PID must be the ID of the JVM process to be inspected. `jps -l` will list the available processes.

Alternatively, use YourKit to take a memory snapshot:

- [Download YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/download/) and extract it
- Use the [Console Attach Wizard](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/attach_wizard.jsp) e.g. `bash ./YourKit-JavaProfiler-2021.3/bin/attach.sh`
- Capture a memory snapshot: `java -jar ./YourKit-JavaProfiler-2021.3/lib/yjp-controller-api-redist.jar localhost 10001 capture-memory-snapshot`

Sources:

- [Java diagnostic command (jcmd) tool](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/tool_jcmd/)
- [Support of Portable Heap Dumps (.phd)](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/phd.jsp)
- [YourKit - Command line tool to control profiling](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/command_line_tool.jsp)

Comment: Just an additional tip. once you create the .phd dump, you can use the *Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)* tool with *IBM Monitoring and Diagnostic Tools* plugin to see its contents, possible leaks, etc. See Analyzing Dumps sections [here](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/dump_heapdump/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-Xdump:heap:events=user` to enable heap dump when signal 3 is passed to OpenJ9 JVM. So, start you application with this option and then issue `kill -3 <pid>` to get the heap dump.

You can also use [Xdump Option Builder tool](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/tools/xdump_option_builder.html) for generating the `-Xdump` options based on your requirement.